# Trying to get id parameter with nodejs and acces it in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, parameters

I am trying to access a detail page that i have for a list of items in my html(ionic). So when I click on 1 item I need to go on a detail page with information about that specific item. I am using mongo database for the items , the model of the items are : name and ingredients.

I am stuck here and don't know what to do , please help if you have a bit of time , thank you.

My code :

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let recipe of recipes ; let i = index">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{recipe.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

Request for the database trying to get the id to access the item  (I get the

```
public findByName(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      "http://localhost:9020/:id" + id
    );
  }
```

This is what I tried in typescript

```
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap) => {
      if (!paramMap.has("id")) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack("/home");
        return;
      }

      this._recipeDetail = this.nutService
        .findByName(paramMap.get("id"))
        .subscribe((id) => {
          this.id = id;
        });
    });
```

Also in route module :

```
{
    path: "name/:id",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./r-d/r-d.module").then(
        (m) => m.RDPageModule
      ),
  },
```

But its not working , maybe I don't have the right approach? Can someone please guide me a bit ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: "http://localhost:9020/:id" + id =>`http://localhost:9020/${id}`

Comment: In Angular your URL should be: `'http://localhost:9020/'+id`

Answer (score 0):

```
this._recipeDetail = this.nutService
    .findByName(paramMap.get("id"))
    .subscribe((id) => {
      this.id = id;
    });
```

You should be expecting your api to return you the recipeDetail.. you are not storing it properly.

```
this.nutService.findByName(paramMap.get("id"))
    .toPromise().then((data) => {
      this.recipeDetail = data;
    });
```

And then, you can display your recipeDetail inside your template. I have also changed `.subscribe()` to `.toPromise().then()`. This is a better approach to avoid memory leaks in your app.